# Explanation needed for some lines of program from LCD liquid crystal program

Tags: c++, utf-8, arduino, 3d

Can someone explain with what will the retval be compared to (bitwise OR) at the end? I dont understand this line of program

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    retval |= (digitalRead(_data_pins[i]) == HIGH)?(1 << i):0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized, `a |= b` is equal to `a = a | b`.

For your code, the expresison

```
retval |= (digitalRead(_data_pins[i]) == HIGH)?(1 << i):0;
```

is equal to

```
retval = retval | (digitalRead(_data_pins[i]) == HIGH)?(1 << i):0;
```

That is, `retval` itself isn't compared to anything. Instead it's previous value is used  with a bitwise OR and the result of that is assigned back to `retval`.

And if we rewrite the conditional expression into an `if else` statement, it would be like

```
if (digitalRead(_data_pins[i]) == HIGH)
    retval = retval | (1 << i);
else
    retval = retval | 0;
```

This should hopefully be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helps me to understand. I'm sorry i'm quite a beginner